# Windows Server 2008 R2 error 1053 apache

Tags: apache, service, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a simple PHP application running on this server which allows other people to verify some information on-line. The apache was running OK until a few days back. 
The application uses Postgrees and the apache service was configured by an add-on "Enterprise Db Apache", it was not configured by me and is connected to a portal to be shown on-line. This was kinda dropped on me and I had no prior knowledge or experience with databases nor servers and need to put it back on-line. How can I start to find out what made it stop?

Here's a link to the error I'm receiving when trying to start it back again:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12837412/Erro%201053.png

Tried updating .NET to no success, 
I've searched around SO and all the threads I found were based on custom services people wrote, and found out that this error code is very generic, I'm very lost and have my neck on the chopping block.

EDIT: Tried some fixes suggested here but had no success. I'm thinking about reinstalling the service, is it a really bad idea? Is there a safe way of doing this without loss of data in the Database? Is there a tutorial on this here already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with compatibility of the versions of C/C++ libraries in the server which lead to the programs related to the service not being able to start properly. A simple reinstalation of the compatible version of the libraries made the service able to be started again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your service is taking longer time than 30 seconds  (Windows default timeout) to start and report ready to the Service Control Manager. Usually this happens because of performance issues.

A possible solution for this is to extend it through the Registry.

1. Go to Start > Run > and type regedit
2. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
3. With the control folder selected, right click in the pane on the right and select new DWORD Value
4. Name the new DWORD: ServicesPipeTimeout
5. Right-click ServicesPipeTimeout, and then click Modify
6. Click Decimal, type '180000', and then click OK
7. Restart the computer

Comment: I've tried a similar fix with timeout set to 60000. Tried the increase on the timeout and unfortunatly didn't solve the issue. And the most intriguing to me is that it did work for a long time and stopped for no reason.

Comment: Try Changing the Log on of the service from Local System account to Network Service.

Comment: I think I might have discovered whats the problem. Looking in the executables from the apache server I tried running some config GUI and it showed me an error with a missing msvcr120.dll, but the tricky part is that it happened after I installed C/C++ 2013 distributables which contains that dll... The error message said that reinstalling the program might solve the issue, but I fear loss of data! Any help you can give me?

Comment: Usually installing library files such C/C++ 2013 will not loss any data, since the data should reside in the database entity only. However, I prefer you take backup on the database side and go through the application configuration to just have a reference in case of any unexpected issues.